# How to use correctly TBitmap object to save a file with transparency?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, vcl, delphi-10-seattle

Below is my sample code:

```
var    lBitmap: TBitmap;
begin
    lBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    lBitmap.PixelFormat := TPixelFormat.pf32bit;
    lBitmap.Transparent := TRUE; // !

    lBitmap.LoadFromFile( 'd:\temp\bmp32b_300dpi_transparent_400x250.bmp' ); 
    // Bitmap RGB+Alpha created with GIMP  

    // modifications on pixels

    Canvas.Draw(100, 0, lBitmap);
    // Up to this point it is correct, the drawing is painted with transparency

    lBitmap.SaveToFile( 'd:\tmp\after.bmp' ); // after this -> I have lost transparency

    lBitmap.Free;
end;
```

How to use correctly TBitmap object to save a file with transparency?

Comment: Many BMP viewers and editors don't support transparency (much less alpha channel transparency). It is better to use PNG. As a bonus, you then get much smaller files..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The purpose of the code is to create a BMP file that contains an alpha channel like a GIMP editor makes.

Comment: "Up to this point it is correct, the drawing is painted with transparency" Are you sure? If I create an ARGB BMP in Gimp and open and draw it like in your code, I get *single-colour* transparency, not *alpha* transparency. The documentation for [`TGraphic.Transparent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Graphics.TGraphic.Transparent) also only mention single-colour transparency.

Comment: I suspect that `TBitmap` doesn't support saving bitmaps with alpha channels.

Comment: Yeah, you probably need to write code to save it yourself

Comment: Fortunately, the BMP file format is trivial, so it isn't difficult to save it manually. Just a couple of simple headers and then an array of RGBA values. Unless someone beats me to it, I might post an example tonight.

Comment: The purpose of drawing is to produce a drawing, not to preserve internal structure. Drawing can draw an image transparently to a device context but it cannot transfer transparency information to that device context.

Comment: To:  Andreas Rejbrand.
Actually. I have prepared a picture with single-colour transparency. And while drawing I didn't see everything.
After this I have prepared a picture with alpha-transparency. After draw on canvas I have more black rectangle.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me like `TBitmap` doesn't support saving bitmaps with alpha channels. And maybe we shouldn't blame the VCL for this, because BMPs with alpha transparency are uncommon. Many applications don't support transparent BMPs.

This being said, I "reverse-engineered" a BMP with alpha channel created in GIMP and wrote the following Delphi routine to produce the very same bitmap:

```pascal
procedure SaveTransparentBitmap(ABitmap: TBitmap; const AFileName: string);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
  BFH: TBitmapFileHeader;
  BIH: TBitmapV5Header;
  y: Integer;
  sl: PUInt64;
begin

  // ABitmap MUST have the GIMP BGRA format.

  FS := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenWrite);
  try

    // Bitmap file header
    FillChar(BFH, SizeOf(BFH), 0);
    BFH.bfType := $4D42;  // BM
    BFH.bfSize := 4 * ABitmap.Width * ABitmap.Height + SizeOf(BFH) + SizeOf(BIH);
    BFH.bfOffBits := SizeOf(BFH) + SizeOf(BIH);
    FS.Write(BFH, SizeOf(BFH));

    // Bitmap info header
    FillChar(BIH, SizeOf(BIH), 0);
    BIH.bV5Size := SizeOf(BIH);
    BIH.bV5Width := ABitmap.Width;
    BIH.bV5Height := ABitmap.Height;
    BIH.bV5Planes := 1;
    BIH.bV5BitCount := 32;
    BIH.bV5Compression := BI_BITFIELDS;
    BIH.bV5SizeImage := 4 * ABitmap.Width * ABitmap.Height;
    BIH.bV5XPelsPerMeter := 11811;
    BIH.bV5YPelsPerMeter := 11811;
    BIH.bV5ClrUsed := 0;
    BIH.bV5ClrImportant := 0;
    BIH.bV5RedMask :=   $00FF0000;
    BIH.bV5GreenMask := $0000FF00;
    BIH.bV5BlueMask :=  $000000FF;
    BIH.bV5AlphaMask := $FF000000;
    BIH.bV5CSType := $73524742; // BGRs
    BIH.bV5Intent := LCS_GM_GRAPHICS;
    FS.Write(BIH, SizeOf(BIH));

    // Pixels
    for y := ABitmap.Height - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      sl := ABitmap.ScanLine[y];
      FS.Write(sl^, 4 * ABitmap.Width);
    end;

  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;

end;
```

This write a [`BITMAPFILEHEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapfileheader) followed by a [`BITMAPV5HEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapv5header) and the pixel data in BGRA format.

I omit all kinds of error checking. For instance, I don't verify that `ABitmap` actually has the required format.

Test:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  bm: TBitmap;
begin
  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bm.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\Test.bmp');
    SaveTransparentBitmap(bm, 'C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\Test2.bmp');
  finally
    bm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

After this, `Test.bmp` and `Test2.bmp` are binary equal.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Saving 32-bit bitmaps with alpha channels needs a workaround as @Andreas Rejbrand has pointed out. There also seems to be some more confusion about the BMP file format, what the `TBitmap.Transparent` property does, and how you draw bitmaps transparently with the VCL.

32-bit bitmaps are the only bitmaps that carry information about transparency in the files. They have that information in the alpha channel and nowhere else. In the alpha channel, every pixel has its own 0-255 alpha value in the RGBA structure. This is often referred to as partial transparency.

When you draw/display 32-bit bitmaps, you have to pay attention to the `TBitmap.AlphaFormat` property. It defaults to `afIgnore`, which means that the bitmap is drawn without transparency. Use `afPremultiplied` or `afDefined` to draw with transparency. The latter is probably what you want.

The `TBitmap.Transparent` property is specific to the VCL `TBitmap`, and there is nothing in the BMP file format that corresponds to it. It's just a simple way to display bitmaps transparently, where a color defines which pixels should be fully transparent. The application must be familiar with the bitmaps to be able to use this method. It's also important to be aware of how the `TBitmap.TransparentMode` property works. It defaults to `tmAuto`, which sets the color of the bottom-leftmost pixel of the bitmap as `TBitmap.TransparentColor`. When `TransparentMode` is set to `tmFixed`, the `TBitmap.TransparentColor` you have specified is used. This method can also be used on 32-bit bitmaps.

Note that when you draw with the standard VCL `TCanvas` drawing routines on a 32-bit bitmap with transparency in the alpha channel, the transparency will be lost where you have drawn.

It seems that in your sample code, you have ignored `AlphaFormat` and `TransparentMode`. You should also decide if you want to use the transparency in the alpha channel or the `TBitmap.Transparent` method. But we have no bitmap in order to check if that is the real problem.

Comment: It's very helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: "TBitmap supports saving 32-bit bitmaps with alpha channels" Yes, it probably can save the bytes, but can any mainstream software (like Windows Explorer) interpret these correctly? It seems to me like `TBitmap.WriteStream` will always use `TBitmapInfoHeader`, which doesn't allow you to specify where the alpha is. At least `BITMAPV4HEADER` is needed for this. So yes, it can save the bytes, but most software cannot open the produced files and interpret the alpha channel! If you can show some example code that uses `TBitmap` to create an ARGB BMP file that Explorer can interpret, I'll c my mind!

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand Ok, now I've found time to really check what you're saying, and indeed, your workaround is needed. The way I've successfully used 32-bit bitmaps over the years has fooled me into believing that the saving worked 100 %. Great!

Comment: Edited my answer so that it includes that a workaround is necessary.